# Qt: typeid alternative

Tags: c++, qt, qtcore, typeinfo

I'm wondering if Qt provides an alternative to typeid to recognize variable types and get their name in a human-readable format.
My specific problem is the following:

```
struct gArgument{
    QString type; 
    void* arg;
};

void gargConverter(gArgument* oArg, T data){
    oArg->type = typeid(data).name();
    oArg->arg = static_cast<void*> (&data);
}
```

the idea would be that of generalizing a variable to use as a input to functions. 
As a side node tyeinfo seems not to be working correctly on my system (I'm using MinGW on Windows 7), if I try:

```
  int i; std::cout <<   typeid(i).name() << std::endl;
  QString s; std::cout <<   typeid(s).name() << std::endl;
  double d; std::cout <<   typeid(d).name() << std::endl;
  float f; std::cout <<   typeid(f).name() << std::endl;
```

I get

```
i
7QString
d
f
```

Any suggestion?

Comment: I think the output for your program is the expected output.  If I change the names of the variables `i`, `d` and `f`, it still gives me those strings.  The exact spelling of the output of `typeid::name()` is implementation defined, and it seems to be giving you a name related to the C++ mangled name for the type.  That makes a certain amount of sense, actually.

Comment: Typeinfo is working as designed on your system. Why do you think there's a problem?

Comment: You may not need Qt for this. Most C++ implementations provide what you need, although it is compiler-specific to an extent.

Comment: @n.m. I was expecting an output similar to [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/typeinfo/type_info/name/), i.e. 'int','QString','double', etc...but I understand this is totally compiler dependent.

Comment: @LaszloPapp yes and I switched to QVariant, thanks! :)

Comment: @LaszloPapp I found it interesting, w.r.t to the second part of the question about typeid() behaviour.

Comment: @LaszloPapp My fault, I'm just getting oriented about how this forum works :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html#typeName):

> `const char * QVariant::typeName () const`
>
> Returns the name of the type stored in the variant. The returned strings describe the C++ datatype used to store the data: for example, "QFont", "QString", or "QVariantList". An Invalid variant returns 0.

This will work for POD and registered built-in Qt types. You would need to use the [following method](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qmetatype.html#qRegisterMetaType) for register your custom type though.

`int    qRegisterMetaType(const char * typeName)`

One another thing you could try, although it is somewhat superfluous to `QVariant` is to work with Object's QMetaObject in the following way:

> `const char * QMetaObject::className() const`
>
> Returns the class name.

and

> `const QMetaObject * QObject::metaObject() const [virtual]`
>
> Returns a pointer to the meta-object of this object.
>
> A meta-object contains information about a class that inherits QObject, e.g. class name, superclass name, properties, signals and slots. Every QObject subclass that contains the Q_OBJECT macro will have a meta-object.
>
> The meta-object information is required by the signal/slot connection mechanism and the property system. The inherits() function also makes use of the meta-object.
>
> If you have no pointer to an actual object instance but still want to access the meta-object of a class, you can use staticMetaObject.

Needless to say, this will only work for QObjects, so not for QString, etc. You would need to create QObject subclasses.

There is also some `QMetaType` that you can use for creation, but [this](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmetatype.html#typ) is a bit different, so I am just mentioning here to be complete:

> `int QMetaType::type(const char * typeName) [static]`
>
> Returns a handle to the type called typeName, or QMetaType::UnknownType if there is no such type.

Here you can find all the types:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtcore/qmetatype.html#Type-enum

Answer (score 1):

You are getting mangled type names. That's perfectly fine, as the behavior is implementation is defined. To get it human-readable, you need to demangle the names on the compilers that do mangle the names (gcc and llvm).

The below works under g++, llvm-c++, and MS Visual C++, so it's about as portable as one can reasonably expect.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#ifndef _MSC_VER
#include <cxxabi.h>
#endif

struct QEvent { virtual ~QEvent() {} };

struct MyEvent : public QEvent {};

#ifndef _MSC_VER
template <typename T> void dumpType(T val)
{
  int status;
  char * realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(val).name(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << realname << std::endl;
  free(realname); //important!
}

template <typename T> void dumpType(T *ptr)
{
  int status;
  char * realname = abi::__cxa_demangle(typeid(*ptr).name(), 0, 0, &status);
  std::cout << realname << std::endl;
  free(realname); //important!
}
#else
template <typename T> void dumpType(T val)
{
  std::cout << typeid(val).name() << std::endl;
}
template <typename T> void dumpType(T *ptr)
{
  std::cout << typeid(*ptr).name() << std::endl;
}
#endif

int main() {
  QEvent * base = new QEvent;
  QEvent * der = new MyEvent;
  dumpType(int());
  dumpType(base);
  dumpType(der);
}
```

Output from gcc and LLVM:

```
int
QEvent
MyEvent
```

Output from MSVC:

```
int
class QEvent
class MyEvent
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like that you are trying to get universal variable, something like [QVariant](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html).
`QVariant` works perfectly for all basic types and all Qt types. Other types can be [registered](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qvariant.html) to qt meta data system.